# How can set vibration option with my game in android?

Tags: android, andengine

I am using AndEngine to develop an Android game and I want vibration to be triggered when an enemy hits a player.

How can I implement this into my game?

Comment: What did you try so far. Where do you run into problems?

Comment: might be better on SO because this is android specific (and it has been [asked there a few times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+vibration) already)

Answer (score 4):

Add this permission to your Manifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

and when there is a collision or something like that (I assume that you're handle the collision detection with AndEngine)

you can add this code :

```
// this is how you get an instance of Vibrator from current Context
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

// this is how you set the vibrate time (its in milliseconds, so if you want it
// to vibrate for 1 sec - write 1000
v.vibrate(300);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the API documentation for the [Vibrator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) here. To determine if the player is hit by an enemy you should lookup a decent tutorial on how collision is handled in AndEngine and add the vibrator code to the collision handler.